# How do I decople a microcontroller with odd number of ground pins?

Tags: msp430, decoupling-capacitor

I'm building a DIP adapter board for MSP430FR5739 and I want to include the decoupling capacitors on the adapter board itself.

From what I can see, I'll need a capacitor on the analogue and digital ground pairs plus one on the Vcore pin whose other side I'd connect to DVSS.

[image]

This leaves me wondering what to do with pin number 38, the second AVSS pin.

What would be the best way to decouple it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intent here is probably to allow a low noise ground region around the crystal oscillator, so run AVSS from pin 3 to 38 and right round any components connected to Xin/Xout in a full loop (aka a guard ring) if you aren't using a full ground plane. And of course it must be joined to DVss somewhere... preferably in just one place to avoid loops, perhaps under the chip to pin 33.

You need a cap from AVCC to AVSS as close to pins 3 and 4 as possible, there is no need for one close to pin 38 but there should be a large (47uf) cap on AVcc to AVss somewhere (ditto for DVcc,DVss)

Answer (score 3):

It should also be decoupled to AVCC. Is this a single or double sided board? Is there a (digital) ground plane on the back of it?

Assuming it's a single sided board with all the traces coming out in a "star" fashion to the DIP pins, I'd just run AVCC under the device (if there's no thermal pad there) and out to a decoupling capacitor to pin 38 somewhere near that end of the device.

Ensure your power/ground traces are wide enough for the maximum possible power consumption of the device.

Comment: I'm planning to do a single sided board.